# Distributing media query emails through Exchange without Outlook 2007

Tags: email, outlook, media-queries, newsletter

I have a problem. We've designed some beautiful, responsive email templates that work across mobile/tablet using media queries but contain MSO conditionals to work on Outlook. Turns out, the client now claims they can only send through an exchange-based mailing list. Ouch.

**Problem:**

- If I send from Mac OSX's Mail, it retains the media queries and works (they are then stripped in Outlook when opened by receiver, but that's inevitable)
- If I send from Outlook, it strips media queries completely and sends without them

From my thinking, the only solutions are:

- Distribute through a different email client that supports both viewport media queries such as Mac Mail and  allows connection to Exchange (know any? Thunderbird?)
- Somehow obtain the mailing list and distribute through MailChimp or similar

Appreciate any advice anyone may have.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how good you care in code and whether you'll need clients to access your system. You can go with user friendly, feature packed options like [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/) or [Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/).

Much cheaper but less featured (relies heavily on you integrating through their api) is [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/)

If you want to stick to free, [PHPList](http://www.phplist.com/) might be a good option.

Comment: Hi John, turns out we can't distribute through an external site, we must distribute through a Microsoft Exchange-based mailing list. Do you know any Mac OS/Windows email clients that will distribute mails with media queries? I know for sure that Outlook won't play nice.

Comment: Maybe try Mozilla Thunderbird.